# Is it possible to generate multiple copies of a value based on count data for that value?

Tags: excel

Didn't know how to phrase my problem into a simple question, sorry!

I have a spreadsheet that is in the incorrect format for what I need to do.
[image]

As you can see, each row is a species of fish, while the column is a unique transect, composed of (a) year, (b) site, (c) reef zone and finally (d) replicate number. The number on the overlap is the number of times this species was recorded in that specific transect.

What I would like to do, is generate a new sheet where each record of a fish on the original spreadsheet is an entire row. This would give a spreadsheet where each individual fish that was recorded now gets its own line, and it would look like this:
[image]
I have very little understanding of anything more than basic Excel, so any help with this would be gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how big your data set is, code might not be necessary. It looks like you could flash fill most of the columns, then sort and paste in your specific transects and species. If you felt you still needed code, then a simple `For` `Next` loop would suffice to write your required unique values.

i.e.:

```
For i = 2 to LastRow
    If
       'code
    Then
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks for this Stan. However, I'm not sure that quite captures what I'm trying to do. 

The dataset is very large, so I expect code will be necessary, and I understand how I could use a for loop to iterate down the whole spreadsheet. However, I don't understand what the code that would actually generate the new lines for each fish species would be.

I've done some research into flash fill, and I really doubt it would understand the pattern  of data I want to extract out of the original spreadsheet.

Comment: @Benfn121 What do you mean as pertaining to "actually generate the new lines for each fish species"? A basic loop will write your values, row by row, wherever you tell it to. If you wanted more specificity you could utilize a `Case Select` loop. This video will help with speed, if the data is very large           [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GCSF5tq7pZ0)

Comment: Perhaps it's better if I re-explain my problem.

In spreadsheet 1 (the incorrectly formatted one), for A. septemfasciatus there were 6 fish recorded in 2002, SAM, S, 3.

For the format I would like, this corresponds to 6 entries (taking up 6 rows) of A. septemfasciatus with year 2002, site SAM, reef zone S and transect 3 (as can be seen in my second image). Each row represents an individual fish that was found on that transect, so there are 3 rows for transect 4 etc.

I don't know what code I would use to generate these entries automatically from the first spreadsheet.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
Const startRow As Integer = 5
Const newSheet As String = "TransposedData"
Sub makeDownwards()
   Dim row As Integer, ws As Worksheet, ows As Worksheet
   Dim oRow As Integer, col As Integer, repNumber As Integer, i As Integer
   Dim fName As String, sName As String, year As String, site As String, none As String, transect As String
   row = startRow
   Set ws = ActiveSheet
   Set ows = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(after:=ActiveSheet)
   ows.Name = newSheet
   oRow = 2
   ows.Range("A1").Resize(1, 6) = Split("Fish Name ,Fish Spicies ,Year ,Site ,None ,Transect", ",")
   ows.Range("A1:F1").Font.Bold = True
   ows.Range("A1:F1").BorderAround xlContinuous, xlThin
   ows.Range("A1:F1").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
   Do While (ws.Cells(row, 1) <> "")
      row = row + 1
      col = 3
      fName = ws.Cells(row, 1)
      sName = ws.Cells(row, 2)
      Do While ws.Cells(1, col) <> ""
         repNumber = ws.Cells(row, col).Value
         year = ws.Cells(1, col)
         side = ws.Cells(2, col)
         none = ws.Cells(3, col)
         transect = ws.Cells(4, col)
         For i = 1 To repNumber
            ows.Range("A" & oRow).Resize(1, 6) = Array(fName, sName, year, side, none, transect)
            oRow = oRow + 1
         Next
         col = col + 1
      Loop
   Loop
End Sub
```